# How to check single byte katakana in a string

Tags: php

Iam working with Double byte japaneese character website, i need to check the user enter a single byte katakana.Site developed in php platform.

This is the preg match that i used for checking
'/[\x{3040}-\x{309F}]/u'

Comment: Something like this? `/\\\\\x3040-\\\\\x309F/u`. PHP has very odd RegEx *ways*. Also you check if "escaped "x" comes around 3040 times, that's not right :)

Comment: Actually this pattern is used for checking katakana, here it checks single and double byte katakana   '/^(\xe3\x82[\xa1-\xbf]|\xe3\x83[\x80-\xbe])+$/'
[http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=12288&names=-&utf8=string-literal]

Comment: @Allendar, preg means perl compatible regex, and in perl a unicode literal is written with the syntax \x{NNNNNN}, so that's probably why the op used that syntax.

Comment: @7stud I see, thanks for the enlightenment :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this the test string I use is legal `$string`. I'll remove the answer (or try to update it) if it works out different. As the string is manual input (escaped the backslash initially), instead of raw;

```
$string = "\\xe3\\x80\\x85"; // RAW input might still be '\xe3\x80\x85' here

$result = preg_match_all("/\\\\xe3\\\\x8[0-3]\\\\x[8-9a-b][0-9a-f]/u", $string, $matches);

echo $string;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

This prints out;

```
\xe3\x80\x85
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => \xe3\x80\x85
        )

)
```

Thus; `々`

Comment: i checked with a single byte character'ァ', but the '$matches' results empty

Comment: Try playing around with the escaping slashes (in this case on all 3 positions it's escaped for RegEx itself *and* PHP, which might be break the match for the bytecode). So each place where the `"\\\\"` are. Maybe in your raw string's case only `"\\"` is enough, but then again, logically, that would only escape it for PHP and still not for the RegEx. Maybe you even need `"\\\\\\"`(6) of them.